# string comparing in csh

Tags: unix, csh

I am searching for a method to use bubble sort on strings in cshell. We have to compare strings if one is greather than other, but I could not find a solution for this problem.

```
if ("test" > "test3") then
    #exchange values
endif
```

Thanks.